# How can I keep my app backstack in the phone's memory

Tags: android, android-memory

I am an avid user of the stackexchange android app and I noticed something peculiar about this app. It has the uncanny ability to keep it's backstack very long in the phone's memory.

This is a practical example: 
I open a question, click a link in the question to another question, do it again, again, again and again several times more. I press the home key, forget about the app and continue using the phone. Several hours (let's say 5) later, I launch the app from the app drawer. The app starts from the splash screen as if starting afresh but no, it resumes from the last page I was before hitting the home button. If I press the phone back button, it takes me back to the previous questions until I reach the the first question I clicked and another backpress exits the app.

But in my own app, the reverse is the case. I click the home button and return to the app about 30 minutes later. The app starts from afresh, no backstack.

How is this possible please?